# Como llamar un metodo java desde un boton en jsp, ayuda por favor!

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, servlets

Hola amigos buenas tardes, espero y se encuentren bien, anteriormente ya había preguntado en otra ocasion y pues por aqui lo redactaré nuevamente para no causar confusión, tengo este codigo java que posteriormente lo meti en un metodo que hice

```
 public void eliminarProcesos(); {
        String fechaMaximaFinal=null;
    String fechaMaximaInicial=null;
        String whereVAAC;
    String whereVAACOpera;

    try {
        if(fechaMaximaInicial.startsWith("00")){
            whereVAAC=" to_date(NB_FECHA,'DDMMYYYY') between to_date('01"+fechaMaximaInicial.substring(2)+"','DD/MM/YYYY') and to_date('"+fechaMaximaFinal+"', 'DD/MM/YYYY') ";
            whereVAACOpera=" to_date(NB_FECHA,'DDMMYYYY') between to_date('01"+fechaMaximaInicial.substring(2)+"','DD/MM/YYYY') and to_date('"+fechaMaximaFinal+"', 'DD/MM/YYYY') ";
        }else{
            whereVAAC=" to_date(NB_FECHA,'DDMMYYYY') between to_date('"+fechaMaximaInicial+"','DD/MM/YYYY') and to_date('"+fechaMaximaFinal+"', 'DD/MM/YYYY')";
            whereVAACOpera=" to_date(NB_FECHA,'DDMMYYYY') between to_date('"+fechaMaximaInicial+"','DD/MM/YYYY') and to_date('"+fechaMaximaFinal+"', 'DD/MM/YYYY')";
        }
        //Aqui es donde borra los registros de las tablas 54 y 49
        this.genericDao.borrarRegistros("VivVAACOpera", whereVAACOpera);
        this.genericDao.borrarRegistros("VivVAAC", whereVAAC);

    }catch (Exception e){
        logger.info("exception: " + e.getMessage());
    }

    }
```

que invoca a un hibernate y ese hibernate genera la sentencia delete mi problema principal es el siguiente, como podría invocar ese método java mediante un botón en un jsp? este el código de mi botón quiero requiero, pero no tengo una idea de como hacerlo:

```
 <input id="#" name="#" type="button" value="Borrar Proceso Completo"   onclick="javascript:borrarAllProcesoVAAC();"/>
```

y como tal esta seria mi funcion de javascript

```
function borrarAllProcesoVAAC(){
            document.getElementById.action="eliminarAllProcesoVaac"
                   document.getElementById.submit();

        }
```

Tengo tambien contemplado realizarlo mediante un `servlet` pero no estoy si es necesario, es el siguiente:

```
public void eliminarAllProcesoVaac(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException{


    }
```

Espero y me puedan ayudar con este problema, quedo al pendiente sino se entiende.

Saludos cordiales.

Answer (score 1):

Para llamar un método del lado del servidor debe crear un formulario que llame al Servlet y este a su vez ejecute dicho método. Un ejemplo para su caso sería así:

**Lado del cliente:**

```
<form action="MiServlet" method="post">
 <input type="submit" value="Borrar Proceso Completo"/>
</form>
```

**Lado del Servidor (Servlet):**

```
public class MiServlet extends HttpServlet {

    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        try {

             eliminarProcesos();
        } finally {
            out.close();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }
}
```

Descripción del proceso:
En el formulario html se apunta al Servlet, el cual llama al método "**processRequest**" que ejecuta la lógica deseada. Debes construir la respectiva respuesta o redireción al recurso deseado. Lo anterior se podría realizar mediante la tecnología AJAX pero ya queda a su disposición.